# Insert/Update SQL DateTime From asp.net(C#) System.dateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime

Here is what i am trying to do:

**NOTE:** I don't want to use  parameterized queries.

Code:

```
 refresh_query.Append("UPDATE Table SET ");
 System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
      refresh_query.Append("date='" +now + "' ");
      refresh_query.Append("WHERE user_id='1'");
```

which results in this query:

```
 UPDATE Table SET date='25/02/2014 12:04:00'
 WHERE user_id='1'
```

getting the following error:

```
   An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll 
but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data 
type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Comment: Pretty much every database engine out there has something that returns the current date and time.  Why not use that instead of dicking around with passing strings?

Comment: It's also better practice to use parameterized SQL queries

Comment: i am not using parameterized SQL queries, because i am building the query with if statments, i may have date = ... , date2 = ..., date4 =

Comment: @DanBracuk i did put "Now" as example, to show that it is System.dateTime format, but i do some calculations and then i want to put it on database, any suggestions?

Comment: @DanBracuk post your comment as an answer, i will accept it. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much every database engine out there has something that returns the current date and time. Why not use that instead of passing strings?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
refresh_query.Append("date='" +now + "' ");
```

to

```
refresh_query.Append("date='" +now.ToString() + "' ");
```

Comment: This approach will not work in case when DB using another culture

Comment: @MikkaRin how do i know what culture is my DB using?

Answer (score 0):

Check how date stores in `sql` by using

`select getdate()`

In your code

```
refresh_query.Append("date='" +now.ToString(_formatExpression_) + "' ");
```

where *formatExpression* - is format that corresponds to format of date in your `SQL` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx#properties)